# Have an issue with input command

Tags: python

Hi I'm a student and a real beginner in python. My assignment is to write a program that prints your input blood type. My code is

```
x=input("Enter your blood type: ")
if x == O:
    for y in range(6):
        print("O O O O O O")
elif x == A:
    for y in range(6):
        print("A A A A A A")
elif x == B:
    for y in range(6):
        print("B B B B B B")
elif x == AB:
    for y in range(3):
        print("AB AB AB")
else:
    print("N/A blood type! Are you alien?")
```

Like this. Whenever I compile it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\muziek\Desktop\q1.py", line 2, in <module>
    if x == O:
NameError: name 'O' is not defined
```

Help please?

Comment: `O` is currently seen as a _name_, as your error message tells you. I'm assuming you want it to be a string. Read about strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For something to be a string in Python, it needs quotes around it. Right now Python thinks that `O` etc. are variables.
Fixed:

```
x = input("Enter your blood type: ")
if x == 'O':
    for y in range(6):
        print("O O O O O O")
elif x == 'A':
    for y in range(6):
        print("A A A A A A")
elif x == 'B':
    for y in range(6):
        print("B B B B B B")
elif x == 'AB':
    for y in range(3):
        print("AB AB AB")
else:
    print("N/A blood type! Are you alien?")
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you are trying to compare a variable `x` with any number of other variables, `O`, `A`, `AB`, `B`. None of the last four is defined, so you will always get a `NameError`.

You probably meant `x == 'O':`, and so on, instead.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

You need to make `O` a string by putting it in quotes.

Make the following changes:

```
x = raw_input("Enter your blood type: ")
if x == "O":
    for y in range(6):
        print("O O O O O O")
elif x == "A":
    for y in range(6):
        print("A A A A A A")
elif x == "B":
    for y in range(6):
        print("B B B B B B")
elif x == "AB":
    for y in range(3):
        print("AB AB AB")
else:
    print("N/A blood type! Are you alien?")
```